# How to set style class on td based on a condition

Tags: html, css, jsp

My requirement is if condition is true, style_class should be appended to td. otherwise no style class should be appended. Tried both of the below statements but with no luck. style_class is appended irrespective of the result of the condition

```
<td class="#{(${test eq true}) ? style_class : }">Test_Text</td>

<td class="#{(test eq true) ? style_class : }">Test_Text</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three are working for me.

```
<td class="${test eq true ? 'style_class1' : 'style_class2'}">

<td class="${test ? 'style_class1' : 'style_class2'}">

<td class="${test eq true && not empty test2 ? 'style_class1' : 'style_class2'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td class="${(test eq true) ? 'style_class' : }">Test_Text</td>`